# IOS- navigation to main view after reopening of application

Tags: ios, authentication, navigation

i am working on an iPhone project in which i create login page.
i want when user logged on to the app after then every time he/she open app he automatically logged to app.
It is now working in my app (user id and password are save) now i want after login the next time user open the app first view shows on screen is main view apart from login view.

my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        checked=[standardDefaults boolForKey:@"boxIsChecked"];
        userid.text=[standardDefaults objectForKey:@"email"];
        password.text=  [standardDefaults objectForKey:@"password"];
        [self checkTheBox];
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }



-(IBAction)CheckBtn_click:(id)sender
{

NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if(!checked)
{
    //NSLog(@"The value of the bool is %@\n", (checked ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
    [CheckBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pro-checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    checked=YES;
    [standardDefaults setBool:checked forKey:@"boxIsChecked"];
    [standardDefaults setObject:userid.text forKey:@"email"];
    [standardDefaults setObject:password.text forKey:@"password"];
}
else if(checked)
{
    [CheckBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Check-Box.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    checked=NO;
    [standardDefaults setBool:checked forKey:@"boxIsChecked"];
    [standardDefaults setObject:NULL forKey:@"email"];
    [standardDefaults setObject:NULL forKey:@"password"];
}
[standardDefaults synchronize];
}

-(void)checkTheBox
{
if(!checked)
{

    [CheckBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Check-Box.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else if(checked)
{
    [CheckBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pro-checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
}
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202332/xcode-ios-check-if-user-is-logged-in-and-show-different-views-if-not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is to add a new view controller in your Storyboard and set it as the initial view controller (if you use Storyboard). Then, create a subclass for that new view controller and implement this kind of logic:

```
// in initial view controller
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (isLoggedIn) {
        // user is logged in, so segue straight to the main view
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"main" sender:self];
    } else {
        // user isn't logged in, so segue to login view
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
    }
}
```

You then need to add segues from the initial view controller to your login page (and set the segue identifier to `login`) and to your main app view controller (and set the segue identifier to `main`).

**Also note that you should never store passwords as plain-text in `NSUserDefaults`, because anyone can access them way too easily.** Don't do that. Instead, store them in Keychain. Here is a great tutorial you should read: http://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your appdelegate(did Launch)

You could just select the specific nib from storyboard. 
Note- Add identifier to your xib. i.e [LoginView] in this case

```
if (isLoggedIn)
{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    LoginView *loginView=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];
    UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginView];
    [loginView setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    self.window.rootViewController=loginView;
}
else
{
// your normal login code
}
```