# Send array of Query strings from iOS to PHP

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

So, basically I have an array with INSERT queries which were generated in the iOS app, and I need to send them to a PHP Script for processing.

I needed help as to how to set up the POST request on the iOS side, to send the array to PHP.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038677/how-to-maintain-a-session-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

you can use AFNetworking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to make the post request.

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://samwize.com/"]];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                        path:@"http://samwize.com/api/pig/"
                                                  parameters:@{@"name":@"piggy"}];
```

Code attribution and tutorial: http://samwize.com/2012/10/25/simple-get-post-afnetworking/

And you can see a very nice tutorial here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

For this one possible solution is to just make a string which contains all the items of array separated by a special character. Now at server side, you can get this string and make array their by breaking string with the special character used.

Example:

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"item 1",@"item 2",@"item 3",@"item 4", nil];
NSMutableString *testStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < [arr count]; i++) {
    if (![testStr length]) {
        [testStr appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
    } else {
        [testStr appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"*%@",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }


}
NSLog(@"%@",testStr);
```